# Column-wise operations in reCsvEditor (Column Fill)

Tags: csv

I have a csv file which is too large to open with Excel.  So I downloaded reCsvEditor which can handle my csv file which is around 2.3 million rows.

I have the need to apply a few column-wise operations on this data.  One thing I need to do is to copy/paste a column's worth of data.  If I have a text editor open, I can copy and paste in that fashion a small number of values quickly, however it is difficult to paste too many values for this column at one time in this way and really 2.3 million rows is a chore.

So what would be nice is to know how to fill a column.  Say I want to fill an entire column with all 0's.  Is it possible to do with this tool, or is this expecting too much?

I would tag this reCsvEditor, but lack the rep to do so currently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible (via Macro / Script). There is a wizard to help build this
sort of script

- Select **Utilities >> Script Build >> UpdateScript**
- On the first screen select `selection fields` and `Update fields and hit the **build** *button*

[image: select fields]

- Update the script as required and hit the run button. You can save the script for future use.

[image]